# Payable transaction to contract keeps failing

Tags: solidity

Hello i have this solidity code in the contract of a token, to receive ETH, send token to sender at an exchange rate and transfer ETH to owner, however on sending ETH to the contract, it fails. Please have an idea of what the issue might be

```
      function () public payable {
        fundTokens();
    }

    function fundTokens() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint256 tokens = msg.value.mul(exchangeRate);
       require(balances[this].sub(tokens) > 0);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        balances[this] = balances[this].sub(tokens);
        Transfer(msg.sender, owner, msg.value);
       forwardFunds();
    }

    function forwardFunds() internal {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

Comment: Try this simple debugging technique - comment out all lines in `fundTokens` but the first one, try transactions. When it works - uncomment one more line and iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for your input, @Chiro Nobuhiro.
I was able to solve the issue by increasing the gas limit, apparently the transaction needed more gas

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check it https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html?highlight=receive#receive-ether-function. Your code would consumed whole 23,000 Gas.

In your case, you better to try this:

```
    address payable owner;
    
    receive() external payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```